# How do I uninstall old SDKs?

Tags: macos, developer-program

I recently upgraded to Apple OS X 10.8 but I observed the following folders in `/Developer/SDKs`:

- MacOSX10.5.sdk
- MacOSX10.6.sdk

I googled and found out that I should run `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`.

However I forgot the `--mode=all` and now I still have the SDK folders but the uninstall-devtools script has gone. I have also installed Xcode 4.5.2 but it seems that it does not come with the command line tool called `uninstall-devtools`.

How can I get rid of the old SDKs?

Answer (score 2):

The installer for [Xcode 4.3](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html) had an option for removing older versions of Xcode which removed /Developer/.

You can probably just delete the folder completely. It was possible to delete single developer folders even before Xcode 4.3. From an [answer by Chris Espinosa on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2605059/495470):

> If you have multiple Developer folders, you can drag any of them to the trash without damaging the others. Developer folders are completely standalone.